# Tomcat RewriteValve/mod_rewrite with Windows style paths

Tags: tomcat

I am running Tomcat 9 on Windows Server. I would like to set-up a RewriteValve/mod_rewrite rule that tests for the presence of a file on the OS.

The docs here suggest it can be done on *nix machines

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=115522372

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html

```
RewriteCond /var/www/maintenance/ALL -f
```

So the RewriteCond tests for the existence of the file using "-f"

However I can't get this to work with Windows style "C:.." paths. I'm pretty sure because this piece of internal Tomcat code (org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot) causes the path to fail validation as its looking for it to begin with a "/"

```
private String validate(String path) {
        if (!getState().isAvailable()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(sm.getString("standardRoot.checkStateNotStarted"));
        }

        if (path == null || path.length() == 0 || !path.startsWith("/")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(sm.getString("standardRoot.invalidPath", path));
        }
```

Any ideas? I suspect I've missed something noddy.

Comment: RewriteCond is Apache _httpd_ syntax (and the Wiki you link to is for httpd), while you mention Apache _Tomcat_ and show Java code. Both have nothing to do with each other. Where do you try to configure this option? Also, this looks borderline off topic ([help/on-topic]) as it seems configuration- not programming-related (even though you cite some code)

Comment: @OlafKock thanks for the reply. I mentioned RewriteCond, which you correctly state is httpd, as well as Tomcat cat RewriteValve (java) as the both use *virtually* the same syntax - RewriteValve is based on RewriteCond: "The rewrite valve implements URL rewrite functionality in a way that is very similar to mod_rewrite from Apache HTTP Server." Indeed the RewriteValve state that "'-f' (is regular file)
Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.". My issue remains though - the RewriteValve doesn't seem to support WIndows style paths.